# Export UIImage array to video - bluish result

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm using `AVAssetWriter` with `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` to make a video from an array of `UIImage`. The result movie is playing fine, but has a blue tint all over them. I know the pixel format is not correct but don't know enough to fix the problem.

`AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` code:

```
NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];
```

Generate `CVPixelBufferRef` from `CGImageRef`

```
+ (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
    CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: @(NO),
                              (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: @(NO)
                              };
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameSize.width,
                                          frameSize.height,  kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pixelBuffer);
    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    void *data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, frameSize.width, frameSize.height,
                                                 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer), rgbColorSpace,
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    return pixelBuffer;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `CGBitmapContextCreate` you should pass `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst` and not `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`.

This is because your bitmaps are laid out as alpha then colour and not colour then alpha.

The reason this got you a bluish tint is because you were treating ARG as RGB. A (alpha) was zero, so your image had no red in it. Removing all red from an image will, in general, give you a bluish-green tint.